# Проблема с доступом к переменным после применения шаблона

Tags: c++, классы, visual-c++, шаблоны-проектирования

Есть некоторая рабочая программа, нужно применить паттерн одиночка на эту программу. 
При моей попытке использовать его, выдает ошибку:

> нарушение прав доступа при чтении по адресу 0x00000000

Как я понял, проблема в ссылочной переменной, но не могу понять конкретнее, а очень хотелось бы.

Сократил максимально программу, чтобы было явно видно в чем проблема

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class Test
{
private:
    static Test* p_instance;
    Test() {}
    Test(const Test&);
    Test& operator=(Test&);

    int N = 5;

public:
    static Test* getInstance() {
        if (!p_instance)
            p_instance = new Test();
        return p_instance;
    }

    void func1()
    {
        cout << "N = ";
        cin >> N;
    }
};

Test* p_instance = 0;

int main()
{
    Test::getInstance()->func1();

    return 0;
}
```

UPD: сделал правку в коде по замечанию комментатора, изначально обращался к p_instance напрямую.

UPD2: То что отмечено как ответ актуально только для обращения к p_instance, код в вопросе после UPD тоже рабочий, прошу прощения за такую путаницу

Comment: *Сократил максимально программу* - тогда было бы `int * p{}; int v = *p;`, то бишь объявляется нулевой  указатель и разыменовывается. Ниужели вас не смутило, что `getInstance` ни разу не вызывается?

Comment: После правки (которая в UPD) всё заработало? Глобальный p_instance теперь нигде не используется, и ошибки быть не должно.

Comment: Да, как оказалось и так всё работает, просто делал всё непоследовательно, поэтому запутался немного

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ну, во-первых, ваше

```
Test* p_instance = 0;
```

не имеет отношения к

```
static Test* p_instance;
```

из класса. Правильно надо объявлять вот так:

```
Test* Test::p_instance = 0;
```

И тогда все будет нормально :)

Но еще лучше спрятать ваш синглтон еще дальше:

```
static Test* getInstance()
{
    static Test * p_instance = nullptr;
    if (!p_instance)
        p_instance = new Test();
    return p_instance;
}
```

Или даже

```
static Test& getInstance()
{
    static Test p_instance;
    return p_instance;
}
```

Comment: Спасибо большое! Изначально думал, что Test:: мы использовали для того чтобы уточнить пространство имён в случае если main и класс находятся в разных файлах, теперь понял, почему обязательно нужно использовать Test::